# Boundaries with jquery mouse follow

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2g4sjbr0/1/

What I want is that the rectangle stops following your mouse when your mouse is not in the red area. Also, the rectangle should disappear when your mouse is not in the red area. It should reappear and continue following your mouse when re-entering the red area.

I can't figure it out, so thank you in advance

HTML:

```
<div id="area">
<div id="rectangle"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#area {
width: 200px;
height: 100vh;
background-color: red;
}

#rectangle {
position: absolute;
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
background-color: black;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
$('#rectangle').css({
    left: e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY
});
});
```

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/2g4sjbr0/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maybe simply do:

```
$("#area").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#rectangle").hide();
});

$("#area").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#rectangle").show();
});
```

Updated your fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2g4sjbr0/3/

Comment: If you want it a bit more _coool_, you could add `$("body").css("cursor","default");` when the mouse leaves `#area` and `$("body").css("cursor","none");` when the mouse enters it. http://jsfiddle.net/2g4sjbr0/8/

Comment: This could be made a single hover function as well : http://jsfiddle.net/81ke3uw3/.

Answer (score 0):

I think that some kind of optimization will be needed cose I think that mouse goes somethimes out of area..

http://jsfiddle.net/mkdizajn/5vp6Lthm/

```
$('#area').on('mousemove', function (e) {
    $('#rectangle').css({
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2g4sjbr0/10/)
qBasic solution! : D

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
    var y_a = $('#area').offset().top  + ($('#area').height()*1 - 25);
    var x_a = $('#area').offset().left + 200-25;
    console.log( [e.pageX,e.pageY,x_a, y_a] );
    if ((e.pageX < x_a) & (e.pageY < y_a)){
    $('#rectangle').css({
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY
    });}
});
```